# how to expand table view cell?

Tags: swift

I create expand tableview with header.
here i get a problem that i didn't get tableview cell index path to expand the tableview cell.

```
   @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
   var hiddenSections: [Int] = []
```

I took button for header cell

```
  @IBOutlet weak var tapBtn: UIButton!
```

in my view controller

```
  public func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 5
    }
  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
      return 3
    }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
 let  headerCell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "header") as! HeaderCell?
headerCell?.tapBtn.tag = section
        headerCell?.tapBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(headerPressed(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)
        return headerCell
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = keycontactsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expandCell") as! expandCell?

return cell!
}

 @objc func headerPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        print("Header tapped %@", sender.tag as Any)

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: sender.tag)
        print(indexPath)
        if hiddenSections.contains(sender.tag)
        {
            hiddenSections.remove(at: hiddenSections.index(of: sender.tag)!)
            myTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sender.tag) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
            myTableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)

        }
        else
        {
            hiddenSections.append(sender.tag)
            myTableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sender.tag) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
        }
    }
```

how to expand cell on headerPressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Storyboard**

[image]

**Code**

```
import UIKit

class ExpandCollapseViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var expTblVw: UITableView!

    var expandData = [NSMutableDictionary]()
    var binType = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for _ in 0..<5
        {
            self.expandData.append(["isOpen":"1","data":["ONCE A WEEK","TWICE A WEEK","EVERY TWO WEEKS","EVERY THREE WEEKS","ONCE A MONTH"],"isSelect":"No"])
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    //MARK: - Tableview Delegates

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.expandData[section].value(forKey: "isOpen") as! String == "1"{
            return 0
        }else{
            let dataarray = self.expandData[section].value(forKey: "data") as! NSArray
            return dataarray.count
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.expandData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 45
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:expTblvwCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! expTblvwCell
        let dataarray = self.expandData[indexPath.section].value(forKey: "data") as! NSArray
        cell.lblTitle.text = dataarray[indexPath.row] as? String
        let selData = self.expandData[indexPath.section].value(forKey: "isSelect") as! NSString
        if selData == "No" {
            cell.lblImg.image = UIImage(named: "round2")!
        } else {
            if selData.intValue == indexPath.row {
                cell.lblImg.image = UIImage(named: "round1")!
            } else {
                cell.lblImg.image = UIImage(named: "round2")!
            }
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
    {
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 45))
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 9, width: headerView.frame.size.width - 50, height: 27))
        let img = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: headerView.frame.size.width-50, y: 9, width: 27, height: 27))
        if self.expandData[section].value(forKey: "isOpen") as! String == "1"{
            img.image = UIImage(named: "drop_down_arrow_black")!
        } else {
            img.image = UIImage(named: "drop_up_arrow_black")!
        }
        headerView.backgroundColor = .white
        headerView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        headerView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        headerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        label.text = (binType[section]).uppercased()
        label.textColor = UIColor(red:0/255, green:173/255, blue:250/255, alpha: 1)
        headerView.addSubview(label)
        headerView.addSubview(img)
        headerView.tag = section + 100
        // self.tblFrequency.tableHeaderView = headerView.
        let tapgesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self , action: #selector(self.sectionTapped(_:)))
        headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapgesture)
        return headerView
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.expandData[indexPath.section].setValue(String(indexPath.row), forKeyPath: "isSelect")
        self.expTblVw.reloadData()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2, execute: {
            self.expandData[indexPath.section].setValue("1", forKey: "isOpen")
            self.expTblVw.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section), with: .automatic)
        })
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let FooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 10))
        FooterView.backgroundColor = .clear
        return FooterView
    }

    @objc func sectionTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if(self.expandData[(sender.view?.tag)! - 100].value(forKey: "isOpen") as! String == "1"){
            self.expandData[(sender.view?.tag)! - 100].setValue("0", forKey: "isOpen")
        }else{
            self.expandData[(sender.view?.tag)! - 100].setValue("1", forKey: "isOpen")
        }
        self.expTblVw.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: (sender.view?.tag)! - 100), with: .automatic)
    }  


}

class expTblvwCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblImg: UIImageView!
}
```

**Result**

[image]